# Is there a way to account for study quality in meta/metaprop?

Tags: r, r-forestplot

I'm conducting a prevalence meta-analysis (i.e., what is the prevalence of [behaviour] in [disease]). I've been using meta and metaprop and finally have a forest plot and output!

I am wondering if there is a way to tell metaprop to adjust the weight of each study based on a quality measure? So each study has a calculated quality value between 0-1, and I want good quality studies (with a quality value of 1) to be weighed more than poor quality studies (with a quality value closer to 0). From what I can tell, each study is weighted equally right now using metaprop. Is there a way to do this?

Also, how do I fit the figure window to the data rather than manually adjusting it for the forest plot?

I've read through the help file for metaprop and don't see a quality value option to add into the code.

For the figure, I've just manually adjusted the height and width of the figure when exporting.